# How to return the insert statement to execute it by java code and not by stored procedure

Tags: plsql

I have one stored procedure which has 10 select statements and one insert statement. Insert statement inserts the data in a table which is set by 10 select statement. But I want this insert statement should not be executed in stored procedure itself but I want 10 select statements should send back these 10 selected values to java code and then in java code insert statements should be executed. Following is the stored procedure and Please provide me java code for this.

Java Code:

```
      CallableStatement objStatement= null; 
Connection objConnection = getConnection(); 
try { objStatement = objConnection.prepareCall("{call test_proc(?)}"); objStatement.setDate(1 , new java.sql.Date( sysdate1.getTime())); objStatement.executeUpdate();   
} catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
log.info("There is some problem in Data Generation : Exception"+e);
```

procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "test_proc"(
    p_fromdate DATE)
AS
  fromdate DATE;
  todate DATE;
  emp_id            NUMBER := 0;
  emp_address       NUMBER := 0;
  emp_dob           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_doj           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_msisdn        NUMBER := 0;
  emp_name          NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_number NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_type   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_middle_name   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_last_name     NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO emp_id FROM employee ;
  SELECT address INTO emp_address FROM employee ;
  SELECT dob INTO emp_dob FROM employee ;
  SELECT doj INTO emp_doj FROM employee ;
  SELECT msisdn INTO emp_msisdn FROM employee ;
  SELECT name INTO emp_name FROM employee ;
  SELECT vehicle_number INTO emp_vehicl_number FROM employee ;
  SELECT vehicle_type INTO emp_vehicl_type FROM employee ;
  SELECT middlename INTO emp_middle_name FROM employee ;
  SELECT lastNAme INTO emp_last_name FROM employee ;
  INSERT
  INTO test
    (
      idofEmp,
      Empaddress,
      Empdob,
      Empdoj,
      Empmsisdn,
      Empname,
      Empvehicle_number,
      Empvehicle_type,
      Empmiddlename,
      EmplastNAme
    )
    VALUES
    (
      emp_id,
      emp_address,
      emp_dob,
      emp_doj,
      emp_msisdn,
      emp_name,
      emp_vehicl_number,
      emp_vehicl_type,
      emp_middle_name,
      emp_last_name
    );
END;
```

Please ignore datatypes:

I just want the last insert statement should be executed by java code and not by procedure.I dont want to keep insert statement in stored procedure. please sugggest

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to execute 10 separate SELECT statements to retrieve ten separate fields from EMPLOYEE; you can do this in a single statement:

```
SELECT ID, ADDRESS, DOB, DOJ,
       MSISDN, NAME, VEHICLE_NUMBER,
       VEHICLE_TYPE, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME
  INTO emp_id, emp_address, emp_dob, emp_doj,
       emp_msisdn, emp_name, emp_vehicl_number,
       emp_vehicl_type, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name
  FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

However, because there isn't a WHERE clause to limit the number of rows returned, both your original 10 statements and the above statement will fail with a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception if there is more than one row in the EMPLOYEE table.

As far as "returning" an INSERT statement, one way to do this would be to return the text of the INSERT statement so that it could be executed from Java. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(p_fromdate DATE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  fromdate DATE;
  todate DATE;
  emp_id            NUMBER := 0;
  emp_address       NUMBER := 0;
  emp_dob           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_doj           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_msisdn        NUMBER := 0;
  emp_name          NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_number NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_type   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_middle_name   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_last_name     NUMBER := 0;
  strInsert_stmt    VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  SELECT id, address, dob, doj,
         msisdn, name, vehicle_number,
         vehicle_type, middlename, lastname
    INTO emp_id, emp_address, emp_dob, emp_doj,
         emp_msisdn, emp_name, emp_vehicl_number,
         emp_vehicl_type, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name
    FROM employee;

  strInsert_stmt := 'INSERT INTO test ' ||
                      '(idofEmp, Empaddress, Empdob, Empdoj, ' ||
                      'Empmsisdn, Empname, Empvehicle_number, ' ||
                      'Empvehicle_type, Empmiddlename, EmplastNAme) ' ||
                    'VALUES (' ||
                       emp_id || ',' ||
                       emp_address || ',' ||
                       emp_dob || ',' ||
                       emp_doj || ',' ||
                       emp_msisdn || ',' ||
                       emp_name || ',' ||
                       emp_vehicl_number || ',' ||
                       emp_vehicl_type || ',' ||
                       emp_middle_name || ',' ||
                       emp_last_name || ')';

  RETURN strInsert_stmt;
END TEST_PROC;
```

One final bit of advice - in Oracle you shouldn't create objects with lower-case or mixed-case names, as you did by putting "test_proc" in double-quotes. Doing so will cause problems because most people will not expect objects to be named in anything other than the default (upper) case, and because any future use of these objects will require that the name be contained in double-quotes. For example, I believe that to invoke a procedure name "test_proc" (in lower case) from Java you'd need to send the name enclosed in double-quotes, as in:

```
objConnection.prepareCall("{call \"test_proc\"(?)}");
```

And if you have to add an upper-case schema name to the procedure in order to have the name resolved properly it gets even uglier:

```
objConnection.prepareCall("{call SOME_SCHEMA.\"test_proc\"(?)}");
```

In my experience it's best to create objects without putting their names in double-quotes - the names will be stored using upper-case, but you can still refer to them in lower or mixed case because Oracle will convert mixed-case or lower-case names to upper-case if the mixed-case or lower-case name is not in double quotes.

## Edit

If you prefer to use a procedure instead of a function, try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(p_fromdate     IN  DATE,
                                     p_insert_stmt  OUT VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  fromdate DATE;
  todate DATE;
  emp_id            NUMBER := 0;
  emp_address       NUMBER := 0;
  emp_dob           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_doj           NUMBER := 0;
  emp_msisdn        NUMBER := 0;
  emp_name          NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_number NUMBER := 0;
  emp_vehicl_type   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_middle_name   NUMBER := 0;
  emp_last_name     NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT id, address, dob, doj,
         msisdn, name, vehicle_number,
         vehicle_type, middlename, lastname
    INTO emp_id, emp_address, emp_dob, emp_doj,
         emp_msisdn, emp_name, emp_vehicl_number,
         emp_vehicl_type, emp_middle_name, emp_last_name
    FROM employee;

  p_insert_stmt  := 'INSERT INTO test ' ||
                      '(idofEmp, Empaddress, Empdob, Empdoj, ' ||
                      'Empmsisdn, Empname, Empvehicle_number, ' ||
                      'Empvehicle_type, Empmiddlename, EmplastNAme) ' ||
                    'VALUES (' ||
                       emp_id || ',' ||
                       emp_address || ',' ||
                       emp_dob || ',' ||
                       emp_doj || ',' ||
                       emp_msisdn || ',' ||
                       emp_name || ',' ||
                       emp_vehicl_number || ',' ||
                       emp_vehicl_type || ',' ||
                       emp_middle_name || ',' ||
                       emp_last_name || ')';
END TEST_PROC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is it possible to return insert string from procedure itself . I dont want to created function. Please suggest.

Comment: An example of how to return the INSERT statement string from a procedure has been added.

Comment: Thank yoouu so much... It is working for me. I just want some more details what datatype should I put  for p_insert_stmt .Because my return string will be very largee..(plz suggest me largest datatype to store the value)

Comment: If the size of the INSERT statement string would exceed 32767 characters you'll need to use a CLOB. The max size of a CLOB depends on the DB_BLOCK_SIZE parameter used when creating your database, and ranges from 8TB to 128 TB.

Comment: Thanks .  Is it possible to execute such separate select statements tin parallel. Not even a single statement is dependent on another. So that the execution time of procedure will be very fast. Right now my table has millions of records.

Comment: Yes - you're looking for the `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package. [Have a look at this article](http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/o30plsql-086044.html). Best of luck.

Comment: My database is read only and it does not have privileges to run create command. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Hello Bob, my deadline is coming soon. Can you please help me here . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of another way to do this.

Comment: ohhkk. let it be.  Thanks for your great support. :)